# trouble implementing zoom in android webview

Tags: android, webview, popup, zooming

I am trying to show a popup in an activity. The layout for my popup contains just a ***webview***. The popup is shown and i'm able to display the contents in the ***webview***. When i'm implementing zoom using `webview.setbuiltinzoomcontrols(true)` the application crashes when i attempt pinch zoom. The code is shown below

```
public void showImageInPopup(String cmImage){

    final String imgSrc = cmImage;
    Log.d("called IMage function", "called IMage function"+cmImage);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override           
        public void run() {
            LayoutInflater searchPopupInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            imagePopupView = searchPopupInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.imageview_popup_layout, null);
            int screenWidth;
            int screenHeight;
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
            screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
            imagePopupWindow = new PopupWindow(imagePopupView,
                    screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2 , true);
            imagePopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
            imagePopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
            imagePopupWindow.showAtLocation(topLayOut, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            imageDisplayWebView = (WebView) imagePopupWindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.imageWebView);
            imageDisplayWebView.loadUrl(imgSrc);
            imageDisplayWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            imageDisplayWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            imageDisplayWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            imageDisplayWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
            imageDisplayWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            imageDisplayWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            imageDisplayWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);             
        }
        }); 
}
```

this function is being called from javascript. Any help please. Thankyou

Comment: can you post your stack trace from logcat?

Comment: 06-27 15:56:30.509: E/InputEventReceiver(2875): Exception dispatching input event.
06-27 15:56:30.509: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2875): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
06-27 15:56:30.519: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2875): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@445a1828 is not valid; is your activity running?   this is the error that occurs when i try to zoom the image in my webview